# How can I download git code by Terraform?

Tags: git, github, terraform

I am trying to checkout git repo code in Terraform and access a file (my_file.py) in it, I used below code,

```
module "my_git_repo" {
  source = "https://git.mycompany.org/my_repo.git"
}
```

output:

```
 "my_display" {
      value       = "${my_git_repo.source}/my_file.py"
    }
```

Error I get is,
Error: Failed to download module
downloading 'https://git.mycompany.org/my_repo.git': no
source URL was returned

Note: I can checkout with "git clone" on command.

Comment: I think you can't download a single file, you need to be more specific as full source code like `source = "github.com/hashicorp/example"`  https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/sources.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `module` block in Terraform is for referring to a Terraform module, not to arbitrary code like Python files.

As Don mentioned, the correct syntax to tell Terraform to obtain a module using git from an HTTPS URL is to add the `git::` prefix, overriding the default handling of HTTP URLs:

```
module "my_git_repo" {
  source = "git::https://git.mycompany.org/my_repo.git"
}
```

However, if you were to use this with a repository that doesn't contain any `.tf` files in the target directory then Terraform will complain that the source address doesn't refer to a valid Terraform module. To get something like what you described in your question you'd need to place at least a minimal Terraform module configuration in that directory too, such as the following `outputs.tf` file:

```
output "python_file" {
  value = "${path.module}/my_file.py"
}
```

Your calling module might then look like this, all together:

```
module "my_git_repo" {
  source = "git::https://git.mycompany.org/my_repo.git"
}

output "my_display" {
  value = module.my_git_repo.python_file
}
```

---

However, this is a very unusual thing to do with Terraform. You didn't mention what your underlying goal is here, but the way you've presented the question makes me suspect that you are trying to do use Terraform to solve a problem it isn't designed to solve. It may be worth asking a new question that is framed more around your underlying problem (*why* do you need this Python file from a remote git repository in your Terraform configuration), where those answering might be able to suggest other ways to solve that problem without forcing the remote repository to behave like a Terraform module.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, Yes I just copied couple lines of code from large terrform file also I will be referencing the python later in TF. Not sure why TF is insisting prefixing "git::" with repo-URL. Many standard apps directly uses the standard repo-URL. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: Terraform needs the `git::` prefix because it supports multiple different protocols that all use HTTP URLs, and Git repositories are not the default protocol for that scheme. You can find information on all of the address formats supported on [Module Sources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/sources.html).

Comment: @MartinAtkins Given a use case such as an infrastructure project to build an AWS Lambda, might be useful to keep the (in this case) Python separate from the infrastructure repo, allow the programmer to iterate their code? Maybe an enterprise context for example?

Answer (score 1):

Change
**source = "https://git.mycompany.org/my_repo.git"**

to
**source = "git::https://git.mycompany.org/my_repo.git"**
to get the source code to download.

Comment: Thanks for your response.